# how to write rules in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am given secure rules like given below. But when testing in rules playground.
When reading & updating - Simulated denied.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Rules playground]

I need to add json data according to my database structure. Given my realtime database structure. How to write secure rules for read & write?

[image: real time database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules don't allow a user to access the whole `/users` collection. In your simulation, you can try accessing the `/users/<uid>` location, that should work fine.

Comment: Yes. I need to write rules for every collections under my realtime database to ensure security.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules as below

```
"users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
```

Excellent documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

.read and .write rules cascade, so this ruleset grants read access to any data at path /foo/ as well as any deeper paths such as /foo/bar/baz. Note that .read and .write rules shallower in the database override deeper rules, so read access to /foo/bar/baz would still be granted in this example even if a rule at the path /foo/bar/baz evaluated to false.

Comment: Updated my question based on your solutions. Which still shows denied in rules playground.

Comment: your data input is correct. you are trying to update uid... you need to update {
  "key": "value"
}